# Another puzzling behavior of getElementById()

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

Try this script: http://jsfiddle.net/8da54/1/. Why is the output different in Firefox and IE?

HTML:

```
<div id="div1">
<div id="div2"><div id="data">data</div></div>
<div id="div3">a-</div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var data = document.getElementById("data");
document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML="";
document.getElementById("div3").appendChild(data);
```

Output:
FF: **a-data** 
IE: **a-**

Comment: Paste your code here.  The Fiddle is not permanent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appears to be one of the many IE `.innerHTML` bugs. In the meantime, you could remove elements the proper way:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("div2");
while (elem.firstChild) {
    elem.removeChild(elem.firstChild);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8da54/2/

Comment: hmm... Thanks for the insight Esailija.

Comment: It's not really a bug actually, It might be the way it is supposed to work :-)

Comment: @Guidhouse [well it's not](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html#innerhtml0). The step 2. of algorithm says that all the children should be removed. It works if we remove them manually like in this answer but IE doesn't do it with their `.innerHTML` properly so it's a bug.

Answer (score -1):

Looking in to the question you're asking. 
Why is the two browsers FF and IE, behaving differently regarding the three lines of JavaScript.

JavaScript usually makes copies of value types and references to objects.
In this particular case, depending on browser, the engines disagree on the implementation.
So when in doubt whether you're copying or referencing. Clone the object if possible to avoid conflicts.

```
var data = document.getElementById("data").cloneNode(true);
//lot's of intensive work with the cloned 'data'-object, function calls etc.
document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML="";
document.getElementById("div3").appendChild(data);
```

This way you are also certain that you have pulled the 'data'-object out of the render-tree and can safely manipulate it in any way, before you insert the result, without to much worry about performance. 
My experience is, that it is always a good idea to avoid working directly in the browser-DOM ( render tree) if in any way possible.

Personally I would keep the the two following lines for clarity, since it is quite obvious what their intend is, and readability always enhance maintainability.
Especially when the performance is the same, if not better(IE).

Comment: ECMA doesn't standardize the dom. There is [w3](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html#innerhtml0)  for that

Comment: Agree on that, but the implementation of 'innerHTML' is Javascript. It manipulates the DOM. The DOM itself is defined by W3C.

Comment: I don't understand. It is perfectly standardized and perfectly defined. It's not hard to know what the implementation should be. IE is bugged.

Comment: @Guidhouse The implementation of `Node.prototype.appendChild` is very well standardized, but not part of ECMAScript. The DOM is an API, it doesn't need to be part of ECMAScript.

Comment: @Esailija innerHTML is not standardised (though I think it might come in with HTML5. Don't remember). It was invented by the IE-team as a convenient way, to manipulate the DOM. And since it quickly gained popularity, the other browsers have implemented similar functionality.  Hence the 'Joke' about MS might have implemented it correctly.

Comment: @Guidhouse It is standardized, I just linked you to the specification.

Comment: Working draft... As I said it's on it's way to standardization. That is not the same as it being standardized. So even if I have plenty of reasons to do IE-bashing( and I do that often enough), this is one of the few areas, where it would be unfair. I am sure that future versions of IE will implement it as described in the draft. But they also have backwards compatibility to think of.